# How to make Firefox open mailto: links with mutt in terminal

Tags: configuration, firefox, mutt

All I want to do is pass `mailto:` links to `urxvt -e mutt -F ~/path/to/muttrc` with the rest of the mailto: URL appended.  I've tried every script I can find online that purports to do this, from simple:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec "urxvt -e mutt -F /path/to/muttrc \"$@\""
```

to [complex](http://www.vinc17.org/mutt/mutt-mailto), and the most they do is open a terminal window for a split second before it automatically vanishes again (and there is no evidence of a running mutt process).  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the quotes, or the shell will try to execute the full string as a command (which obviously does not exist).

```
#!/bin/sh
exec urxvt -e mutt -F /path/to/muttrc "$@"
```

Not tested, but the presence of quotes is the explanation for the vanishing of the terminal.

Comment: Thanks Stephane. It works. I admit to confusion about when to quote `$@` and when not to.

Comment: `"$@"` will result in as many words as the number of arguments. With `$@`, all the arguments will be collapsed and word-split again (usually that's not what you want).

Comment: I have tried this with firefox and I can't seem to get it to work.   I used the EXACT string above (modifying the arg to -F and removing -F and the arg entirely) and for me the console still vanishes..

Comment: I think the problem is, that some terminal emulators don't pass on additional arguments. E.g. if you use the `terminator` term, it provides an `-x` option, which passes conveniently additional arguments to the executing command.

Comment: @romanofski: You're right, with [termite](https://github.com/thestinger/termite/) for example, it's `exec termite -e "mutt \"$@\""`.